# Get AngularJs Service from Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the angularjs service from Plain Javascript. I am using the below syntax.

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'error-handling']).get("messagingService").GetName();
```

When messagingservice does not contain any dependency this is working fine. When the messagingservice contains

```
.service('messagingService', ['$rootScope', 'applicationLogService', 'dialogService', MessageService])
```

then I am getting `Unknown provider: dialogServiceProvider <- dialogService <- messagingService` error. I have included the js file for dialogservice already. Can any one help where I am missing ? Is there any other syntax need to be followed in getting service with dependency?

Comment: post the dialogService js

Comment: It is a big file. I am using the same file in other angular parts and it is working fine. This page is not angular and so I am trying explicitly to inject. Is that any other steps need to done before calling messageservice.

Comment: Why can't you give angular control on this page ? (with ngp-app and small controller)

Comment: @Okazari Yes that is the work around solution I am thinking if this is not going to work. But want to know why this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'error-handling', 'module-that-owns-dialogService' ])
  .get("messagingService").GetName();
```